# Schubert calculus and Pieri's formula

Tags: co.combinatorics, cohomology, characteristic-classes, grassmannians, schubert-cells

In the lecture notes  [Grassmannians: the first example of a moduli space. MIT Open Course Ware.](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-727-topics-in-algebraic-geometry-intersection-theory-on-moduli-spaces-spring-2006/lecture-notes/week1.pdf) page 7:
[image]

Are there any formal publications (books/papers) where I can find the formula?

Comment: I don't know the notations involved (what is a *special* Schubert cycle?), but I suspect that Fulton's *Young tableaux* (Chapter 10 particularly) is an introduction into this.

Comment: Griffiths and Harris, p. 203.  It is also in Fulton and Harris (probably in the appendices).

Comment: And Manivel, most likely.

Comment: @JasonStarr: The word "Schubert" appears only once in Fulton&Harris, and that's in a reference. You might be talking of Fulton? (Or you mean the combinatorial Pieri rule? But that's in many places.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: You are correct.  I was remembering the combinatorial Pieri rule (I don't have a copy of Fulton-Harris here; I have a Russian Griffiths-Harris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have some standard references (quoted in the comments):

- Hiller, Howard. Geometry of Coxeter groups. Research Notes in Mathematics, 54. Pitman (Advanced Publishing Program), Boston, Mass.-London, 1982. iv+213 pp. ISBN: 0-273-08517-4 MR0649068 (83h:14045)
- Fulton, William. Young tableaux. With applications to representation theory and geometry. London Mathematical Society Student Texts, 35. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1997. x+260 pp. ISBN: 0-521-56144-2; 0-521-56724-6 MR1464693 (99f:05119)
- Manivel, Laurent. Symmetric functions, Schubert polynomials and degeneracy loci. Translated from the 1998 French original by John R. Swallow. SMF/AMS Texts and Monographs, 6. Cours Spécialisés [Specialized Courses], 3. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI; Société Mathématique de France, Paris, 2001. viii+167 pp. ISBN: 0-8218-2154-7 MR1852463 (2002h:05161)

Let me add another nice reference:

- Hiller, Howard L. Schubert calculus of a Coxeter group. Enseign. Math. (2) 27 (1981), no. 1-2, 57--84. MR0630960 (82m:14031)

Hiller's paper is freely available online [here](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view2?pid=ensmat-001:1981:27::215).